# How to make echo only 'echo' once when using |

Tags: bash, pipe, echo

##### I am trying to setup an alias to automatically search for an anime on 'ani-cli'

Example of using ani-cli normally with no alias/automation

```
ae@phony:~$ ani-cli
Search Anime: Neon Genesis Evangelion
[1] neon-genesis-evangelion-
[2] neon-genesis-evangelion-dub
[3] evangelion-death-and-rebirth
[4] neon-genesis-evangelion-death-rebirth-dub
[5] neon-genesis-evangelion-the-end-of-evangelion-dub
Enter Number:
```

I've tried using:

```sh
alias ani-nge="echo 'Neon Genesis Evangelion' | ani-cli"
```

The alias does sucessfully look for the anime, but when prompted to choose which series, it returns an Error saying an invalid number was picked, even when I didn't type anything.

```
[1] neon-genesis-evangelion-
[2] neon-genesis-evangelion-dub
[3] evangelion-death-and-rebirth
[4] neon-genesis-evangelion-death-rebirth-dub
[5] neon-genesis-evangelion-the-end-of-evangelion-dub
Enter number: Invalid number entered
```

**I'm newer to bash and the terminal**, so I'm not the greatest at this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it's expecting a number, you need to provide a number, not the title associated with the number.

Comment: @chepner They said they're not typing anything. Sounds like the problem is that `ani-cli`'s stdin (the pipe) is closed.

Comment: Or, if the text being echoed triggers that menu, you need to enter *additional* input in the form of a number. With the pipe, `ani-cli` will not try to read from the terminal; it reads from its standard input, which is closed once the initial `echo` exits. In that case, try something like `{ echo 'Neon Genesis Evangelion; echo 2'; } | ani-cli`. There's no simple way to provide *some* input, then switch back to your terminal for additional input.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, I thought of that almost immediately after posting the first comment, and the second comment took a while to write :)

Comment: Syntax in https://github.com/pystardust/ani-cli shows you can pass query as an argument.

Comment: Unrelated, but for anything more complicated than adding a default option to a command (e.g., `alias ls='ls -l'`), prefer a shell function over an alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing input to `ani-cli` via pipe, and when `echo` is done, the pipe closes, which closes `ani-cli`'s standard input stream (*stdin* for short), which `ani-cli` detects as an error. Then there's no way to provide additional input.

Instead, pass the query as an argument (which [the docs](https://github.com/pystardust/ani-cli/blob/master/README.md) say you can do):

```
ani-cli 'Neon Genesis Evangelion'
```

In the context of the alias:

```
alias ani-nge="ani-cli 'Neon Genesis Evangelion'"
```

Comment: ...though it would arguably be better to use a function and not an alias at all, to get the OP in the habit of using constructs that work more reliably (available in scripts, amenable to conditional logic, etc).

Comment: @Charles I know functions have their place, but this seems like a fine use case for an alias: just providing a default argument, probably only for interactive use.

Comment: @rici, _interactive_ input, I take the OP to mean. Granted, `{ printf '%s\n' 'Neon Genesis Evangelion'; cat; } | ani-cli` would achieve that, but it's liable not to work as-expected otherwise (if the tool looks at whether stdin is a TTY and modifies behavior based on same).

Comment: @wjandrea: right, after the pipe is closed you can't add more input. But you can design the pipe so that it reverts to whatever stdin was before if more input is needed. This is an alias definition, and it is possible to write a "better" one. Obviously in this case the solution you advocate in your edit is better. But `expect` exists for a reason.